# Regular expressions in J2ME

Tags: java, regex, java-me

If I wanted to implement a regex engine in JavaME (Which lacks the regex libraries), where would be the best place to start? I'm imagining there is existing regex code out there which it would be possible to use as a starting point for porting.

Failing that, a good guide on how to compile and execute a regular expression would do.

Answer (score 2):

Could you investigate third party RegEx libraries, such as http://www.brics.dk/~amoeller/automaton/ ?

Could you analyse your requirements and simplify your needs to something that doesn't need a RegEx library?