# Regular expressions in microedition

Tags: java, regex, java-me

How can I use regular expressions in microedition?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462048/regular-expressions-in-j2me

Answer (score 0):

J2ME lacks regular expression libraries.  Please see the answers to [Regular expressions in J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462048/regular-expressions-in-j2me) (which is about *implementing* regex) for some alternative implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are not supported in Java ME.
One reason could be that regular expressions have performance issues as described [here](http://eyalsch.wordpress.com/2009/05/21/regex/). You can't afford compute intensive software on micro devices. Cheers